# Fastest way to redirect with refresh button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I have an issue where after I've selected some products and filtered them I would like to refresh to the home page (in my case - series_list/) where it shows all products and their specifications but without the filters. Basically it should refresh to the home page immediately when I click on the refresh button from the browser.

I tried using:

```
    if (performance.navigation.type === 1) {
        window.location.href = '/series_list/';
    }
```

However, it takes roughly 2-2.5 seconds for it redirect to the home page which is too slow.

Here is the Django code for the products filters and specifications:

```
   {% for key, value in specification_list_fields %}
       <th>
            <a class="table-headers" href="?{% if order_by == key %}order_by={{ key }}_desc{% else %}order_by={{ key }}{% endif %}&{{ query_atrs_wo_order_by }}">
               {{ value }}
                 <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort{% if order_by == key %}-up{% elif order_by == key|add:'_desc' %}-down{% else %}{% endif %}"></i>
           </a>
      </th>
   {% endfor %}
```

Is it possible to redirect even quicker when pressing the refresh button?